# Filling the peaks and troughs of an oscillating 3D curve using alternating colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I would like to fill the peaks and troughs of a circle vibrating with respect to its static configuration using alternating colors. I tried using the `fillbetween` package (with pgfplots 1.15) and it almost works. What should I do in order to obtain the desired result?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    trig format plots=rad,
    view={60}{120}
]

\addplot3 [name path=vibrating, variable=t, domain=-pi:pi, samples=1000, samples y=0] ({cos(t)},{sin(t)},{cos(4*t)});

\addplot3 [name path=flat, variable=t, domain=-pi:pi, samples=100, samples y=0] ({cos(t)},{sin(t)},0);

\addplot3 [fill=gray!5] fill between [
of=vibrating and flat, 
split,
every even segment/.style = {red!20!white}];

\tikzfillbetween[
of=vibrating and flat,
on layer=,
split,
every even segment/.style = {fill=none, draw=none}]{blue,opacity=50}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The issue is that intersections are always intersections of 2D paths, i.e. paths on the screen, and not 3D intersections. Therefore, the intersection segments used in your picture do not match the expectations.

Therefore, it might be worthwhile to slightly switch gears and compute the intersections analytically, which is simple enough in the given setting. And it suffices to use `tikz-3dplot` here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Amplitude}{0.3}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=101]
 \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{0});
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\draw[fill=red] plot[variable=\x,domain=90*\X+360/16:90*\X+3*360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{\Amplitude*cos(4*\x)}) 
 --plot[variable=\x,domain=90*\X+3*360/16:90*\X+360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{0});
 \draw[fill=blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=90*\X-360/16:90*\X+360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{\Amplitude*cos(4*\x)}) 
 --plot[variable=\x,domain=90*\X+360/16:90*\X-360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{0});}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could use pgfplots as well.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    trig format plots=rad,
    view={60}{120}
]

\addplot3 [name path=vibrating, variable=t, domain=-pi:pi, samples=1000, samples y=0] ({cos(t)},{sin(t)},{cos(4*t)});
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Amplitude}{1}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{%
\draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] plot[variable=\x,domain=90*#1+360/16:90*#1+3*360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{\Amplitude*cos(4*\x)}) 
 --plot[variable=\x,domain=90*#1+3*360/16:90*#1+360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{0});
 \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] plot[variable=\x,domain=90*#1-360/16:90*#1+360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{\Amplitude*cos(4*\x)}) 
 --plot[variable=\x,domain=90*#1+360/16:90*#1-360/16,samples=51]
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{0});}

\addplot3 [name path=flat, variable=t, domain=-pi:pi, samples=100, samples y=0] ({cos(t)},{sin(t)},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note also that for much more complex images it might be worthwhile to switch to `asymptote`, which comes with a true 3D engine.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough answer!